# Creating multiple array using a foreach loop and a select statement

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a database that I call select all of its contents of a table. It has 18000+ items. I have a method uses a web service that can have an array of up to ten element pass into it. Right now I am doing item by item instead of by an array. I want to create an array of ten and then call the function. I could make an array of ten and then call the function be what is I have an extra three records?

```
public static void Main()
{
    inventoryBLL inv = new inventoryBLL();
    DataSet1.sDataTable dtsku = inv.SelectEverything();
    foreach (DataSet1.Row row in dtsku)
    {
        webservicefunction(row.item);
    }
}
```

My question is how would I transform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic solution of your problem could look like this:

```
static class LinqHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<T[]> SplitIntoGroups<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int N)
    {
        if (items == null || N < 1)
            yield break;

        T[] group = new T[N];
        int size = 0;
        var iter = items.GetEnumerator();

        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
            group[size++] = iter.Current;
            if (size == N)
            {
                yield return group;
                size = 0;
                group = new T[N];
            }
        }
        if (size > 0)
            yield return group.Take(size).ToArray();
    }
}
```

So your `Main` function become

```
public static void Main()
{
    inventoryBLL inv = new inventoryBLL();
    DataSet1.sDataTable dtsku = inv.SelectEverything();
    foreach (var items in dtsku.Select(r => r.item).SplitIntoGroups(10))
    {
        webservicefunction(items);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get two errors 1 Cannot convert lambda expersion to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type, 2 Does not contain for 'item'.

Comment: Please most more details about your code. As minimum provide `DataSet1.sDataTable` and `DataSet1.Row` class declarations and exact signature of your `webservicefunction`. Otherwise it is difficult to say why you have such errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
var taken = 0;
var takecount = 10;
while(list.Count() >= taken)
{
     callWebService(list.Skip(taken).Take(takecount));
     taken += takecount;
}
```

Generic Extension Method version:

```
public static void AtATime<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int eachTime, Action<IEnumerable<T>> action)
{
      var taken = 0;
      while(list.Count() >= taken)
      {
           action(list.Skip(taken).Take(eachTime));
           taken += eachTime;    
      }
}
```

Usage:

```
inv.SelectEverything().AtATime<Row>(10, webservicefunction);
```

Comment: this is really confusing because it is seemingly in a vacuum.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  The code(pseudocode?) provided will take a list and while there are items to process it will send them 10 at a time to callWebService.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: This works out, but not optimal: `skip` needs to start from the beginning in each call until it reaches `taken`.

Comment: And `Count()` needs to iterate the complete collection

Comment: Yeah, good points, but it's pretty and OP doesn't specify any performance constraints.